# Interpolation inequality of Gagliardo-Nirenberg for compactly supported functions

Tags: inequality, interpolation

It's obvious that for a standard bounded domain $\Omega$ the interpolation inequality of Gagliardo-Nirenberg for a special case, can be written as the following:

If $D^m v$ and $v$ belong to $L^p(\Omega)$ then $D^r v$ belongs to $L^p(\Omega)$ for $r=0,\cdots,m-1$. In addition, we have:
$$ \| D^r v \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C_{\Omega} \left( \| D^{m} v \|_{L^p(\Omega)} + \| v \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \right).
$$

Now, if the support of $v$ is included in a compact $K \subset \Omega$, will the constant $C$ depend on $\Omega$ or on the support $K$ of the function $v$?

Answer (score 1):

**For compactly supported functions, such a Sobolev embedding constant is universal** (it depends only on the parameters, not on the support of the functions).

In the case mentioned above, this follows from the fact that the scaling-invariant Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality reads as follows: there exists $C > 0$ such that, for every $v \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\| D^r v \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}
\leq C \| D^m v \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{\frac r m} \| v \|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{1-\frac r m}.
$$
Then, the associated additive Sobolev inequality follows by Young's inequality for products, with a constant which depends neither on $K$ nor on $\Omega$, as long as $v$ is indeed compactly supported inside $\Omega$.

When $v$ is not compactly supported inside $\Omega$, the scaling invariance is lost and the constant may depend on the size of $\Omega$.